# Why was my question closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I realize that it has no impact on anything but [my question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/what-work-had-the-humans-reinventing-the-space-flight-during-war-having-the-wor?noredirect=1#comment689714_2160) was closed as duplicate despite being asked 3 years earlier, having more answers, being higher upvoted and having more views than another.

Comment: Story id questions are closed as duplicates when they have the same _confirmed_ answer. Here the answer on your question is just lower quality than the one on the one it's closed to (not much better but slightly so).

Comment: I've closed this to the general story id close policy question as we've done in the past for these types of questions. Please ping me if you want to discuss your specific case further and the reasons it was chosen one way or the other though and I'll be happy to.

Comment: The other question (and answer) set are more detailed. You're right that it's borderline though.